# Subir archivo .stl o .obj al servidor con Laravel 8.0

Tags: javascript, laravel

Buenas tardes estoy intentando subir archivos .stl o bien .obj para luego crear una escena con ellos pero no hay forma de subir el archivo.

**Aquí, es como abro la selección de archivo y donde está el input**

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
   <div class="p-2 text-center">
      <a class="pos_addarchivo" id="add_archivo" onclick="thisFileUpload();">
        <img src="{{ asset('images/svg/plus.svg') }}" alt="" class="add_archivo">
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="p-2">
       <h3 class="el_archivo">Añade tu archivo</h3>
       <h4>Formato .stl / .obj | Máximo 100Mb</h4>
       <input type="file" id="file" style="display:none;" accept=".stl, .obj"/>
       <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('file') }}</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

**El Javascript**

```
  function thisFileUpload() {
   document.getElementById("file").click();
    $('input[type="file"]').on('change', function() {
        var file = $(this)[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url('store-file')}}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (res) {
                console.log(res);
            }
            
        })

     });
   };
```

**Las rutas**

```
Route::get('file', [FileController::class, 'index']);
Route::post('store-file', [FileController::class, 'store']);
```

**Controlador FileController**

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('file');
    }
 
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       request()->validate([
         'file'  => 'required|mimes:stl,obj|max:2048',
       ]);
  
        if ($files = $request->file('file')) {
             
            //store file into document folder
            $file = $request->file->store('public/documents');
 
            //store your file into database
            //$document = new Document();
            //$document->title = $file;
            //$document->save();
              
            return Response()->json([
                "success" => true,
                "file" => $file
            ]);
  
        }
  
        return Response()->json([
                "success" => false,
                "file" => ''
          ]);
  
    }
```

Pero todo el rato me devuelve error **422**

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {file: ["The file must be a file of type: stl, obj."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

Comment: ¿Sabes si en el servidor [Apache?] están definidos esos dos tipos de MIMEs?

Comment: Hola @VFG no me lo habia planteado, pero tiene algo que ver?

Comment: Mira https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes. Yo interpreto que no sólo ve la extensión, sino que comprueba el archivo para checkear que es realmente de ese tipo. Entiendo que es una medida de seguridad para no colar archivos peligrosos con extensiones cambiadas.

Comment: Voy a darle un ojo pues, muchas gracias!

Comment: Y si ya estaban definidos esos tipos, mírate también https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60947177/laravel-validator-doesnt-correctly-validate-file-mime-type. Es curioso, pero ya he visto varios sitios más que hablan de "file.*". Tendré que probar